# SendMessageA and SendMessageW in Win7 migrated from WinXP

Tags: c, winapi, windows-7, windows-xp, sendmessage

EDIT: Working code posted below, nonworking code commented out.  You must use the same CHAR_T for retrieving data from windows as you used to create them in Win7.

I have a dialog written in C that works perfectly in WinXP but fails to collect user input from an edit control in unicode in Win7.  The problem occurs on the first call to SendMessageW as shown below:

```
/* handles to controls */
HWND hDomainEdit;
HWND hOtherEdit;
HWND hTextOut;
HWND hButton;
/* buffers to receive input */
WCHAR wszDomain[256];
CHAR szOtherInput[512];
CHAR szBuffer[512]; //added to hold temporary value of wszDomain
/* a test string */
const CHAR szTest[] = "This is a test of SendMessageA."

BOOL dialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    if (message == WM_INIT) {
        /* get all the handles shown above, then... */
        SendMessageA(hTextOut, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM) szTest);
        /* worked fine */
        /* do a few other things */
    } else if (message == WM_COMMAND) {
        /* are some other conditions are true?  they sure are */
        /* time to collect a bunch of input from controls */
        int cchResultLen = (int) SendMessageA(hOtherEdit, WM_GETTEXT, 512, (LPARAM) szOtherInput);
        /* cchResultLen is correctly the length of the user input */
        /* cchResultLen = (int) SendMessageW(hDomainEdit, WM_GETTEXT, 256, (LPARAM) wszDomain); */
        /* begin new code */
        cchResultLen = (int) SendMessageA(hDomainEdit, WM_GETTEXT, 512, (LPARAM) szBuffer);
        cchResultLen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, szBuffer, cchResultLen, wszDomain, 256);
        wszDomain[cchResultLen] = 0; /* above doesn't terminate string */
        /* after SendMessageW(), cchResultLen was 0, no string transferred, no error
           message.  using SendMessageA, all is well. */
    }
}
```

It appears SendMessageA works multiple times with message = WM_GETTEXT or WM_SETTEXT, and suddenly, when a wide string is required, SendMessageW fails.  Now, I know everyone is thinking that you should pick a CHAR_T and stick with it by always using SendMessage, but it's not so; Win32.hlp explicitly notes that it's possible to use both in the same program by calling the individual functions manually.  I'm sure someone else is ready to say that the control itself is or becomes committed to one particular CHAR_T, but that's not the case in WinXP, where this worked perfectly.  That particular edit control is also never set to an ASCII string explicitly.

The program interacts with WinHttp, which requires all WCHAR strings, and that's where the SendMessageW comes in.  The rest of the inputs are only used internally and are primarily parsed integers with unit labels, which are more convenient and efficient in ASCII, if for no other reason than because the program was originally written that way.

So what do?  Have they really changed something as integral as SendMessage to be incompatible?  If so, is it a known bug with a work around, or is the ability to switch CHAR_T at will a deprecated feature?  Is there some other easier way than expanding the input to WCHAR manually after getting it with SendMessageA?

Comment: I'm inclined to think that the error is not in `SendMessageW()`; at least as a starting point. Are you sure `hDomainEdit` is valid? What happens when you use `SendMessageA` on it? Also, why not use `GetWindowText[AW]`?

Comment: sayeth MSDN: "If the target window is owned by the current process, GetWindowText causes a WM_GETTEXT message to be sent to the specified window or control."  so it should be about the same effect.  I'll try checking the value of the handle - it's never used outside of that one statement, so some other problem would be otherwise silent.  It is definitely a valid handle to the correct control in XP, though.

Comment: I'm not saying that you are wrong to use WM_GETTEXT here; but personally I'd prefer API functions to messages, unless there is a reason to do otherwise. Also, MSDN doesn't say whether GetWindowText does anything else besides sending WM_GETTEXT. E.g. there might be some nuances wrt. ANSI/UNICODE conversion (though I don't remember any).

Comment: Perhaps SendMessage is failing for some other reason that's not related to ANSI/UNICODE at all? Try calling SetLastError(0) before it, then using GetLastError() afterwards and see if it's returning an error code. Are the HWNDs here in your own process, or are you trying to get text from another process?

Comment: @BrendanMcK - this probably won't work. At least, the only documented case when SendMessage sets LastError is when it fails due to integrity level violation. Can't hurt though. And we definitely need as many hard facts as we can get.

Comment: tests pending for each of these queries.  atzz - you have a point, in that it could be like EnableWindow().  @BrendanMcK - they are all my own HWNDs from GetDlgItem() in the WM_INITDIALOG message.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I've read somewhere that the last letter tells the character encoding the function uses, e.g. a = ascii and w = wide (unicode?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All window handles were fine.  The folks at MSDN informed me that any window created with an 'A' function - in this case DialogBoxParamA() - must be accessed via the 'A' functions.  As for the fact that it worked in XP, they said "Just because it works doesn't mean it's right".  I suppose that functionality was deprecated - would have been nice to hear about that before it stopped working!

Comment: You did hear about it, you just didn't take heed. It was never meant to work the way you were doing it. You just got lucky. MS is under no obligation to tell anyone about changes to the implementation of their libraries that stay within the published specs.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Link to documentation stating this issue specifically?  I don't see it under Windows Data Types for Strings or SendMessage on MSDN - certainly not in Win32.hlp.  Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317720%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: It's in the [About Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632597(v=VS.85).aspx) topic. "If a window class was registered with the Unicode version of RegisterClass, the window receives only Unicode messages. To determine whether a window uses the Unicode character set or not, call IsWindowUnicode."

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: windows were created with DialogBoxParamA, and the class was registered by the system, not the application - while I concede that it suggests that window classes can be strictly unicode, clearly both versions of the common controls exist.  Link above contrasts: "Applications using the Unicode and character set API functions generally use the same window class. The operating system transparently translates messages between windows of different classes.  [...] The window function can send messages or call functions of either type."

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that if you step through your code with debugger - you will see the reason.

First of all, the two SendMessages you have one after another, they are using different window handles, so they are not of the kind to give you the same result. Let's talk about the one that gives you the problem:

```
cchResultLen = (int) SendMessageW(hDomainEdit, WM_GETTEXT, 256, (LPARAM) wszDomain);
// cchResultLen is ZERO!  wszDomain[0] is null.  Edit control is not empty
```

Standing with debugger on this line, check your **hDomainEdit** variable. Perhaps it's not valid, like NULL or damaged by some other code. This would explain invalid handle and zero result.